# Unusual use of << operator... not a bit shift?

Tags: serial, flash, stream

Poking through the example code of SDFS, I saw the following:

```
static ArduinoOutStream cout(Serial);
// F stores strings in flash to save RAM
cout << F("\ntype any character to start\n");
```

What exactly is << doing in this case? Moreover, F seems to never be defined prior to this. This seems like a useful trick, but I don't understand how it works.

full code available here: https://github.com/greiman/SdFs/blob/master/examples/SdInfo/SdInfo.ino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is << doing in this case?

It's directing the data into an output device (stream).

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Yes, it's confusing using the same symbols for more than one thing...

> Moreover, F seems to never be defined prior to this.

`F()` is a macro. It's defined by the Arduino core in WString.h:

```
#define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your last line there uses the < and > symbols in ways I've never seen as well, along with the pointer. These seem not to be logical or arithmetic operators, so what do I call them in a google search to understand your answer?

Comment: @BoThompson those are template<parameters>

Comment: Compared to the < logical operator and the < arithmetic operator, what would you call that set of symbols?

Answer (score 1):

To address your confusion with the bitshift operator;

It indeed is commonly used as a the arithmetic operator for bitshift, but appears to be 'overloaded', so that when used with streams, it is an 'insertion operator'.

> In particular, stream insertion and stream extraction overloads of
>   operator<< and operator>> return T&.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Basically there would be two definitions of the "<<" operator function:

```
function <<(integer){//Shift bits}
function <<(stream){//Join streams}
```